# How to print or log from a UDF in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I created a UDF in pyspark to do an activity and declared as below.

```
my_udf = udf(lambda z:udf_method(z), StringType())

def udf_method(udf_param):
  try:
    print('In UDF Method')
    if 'something':
      print('SOMETHING')
      return 'SOMETHING'
    else:
      print('NOTHING')
      return 'NOTHING'
  except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Registered it with spark like: `spark.udf.register('udf_method', udf_method)`

I have a dataframe `df` and I am creating a new column in that dataframe by calling a UDF as below.

```
new_df = df.withColumn('udf_output', udf_method(col('some_column_from_my_dataframe')))
new_df.write.mode('overrite').format('ORC').saveAsTable('dbname.tablename')
```

When I ran the code, it was not printing anything in the logs. So I added logging as below to see if there could be any difference.

```
class debugger(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def log(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger(self.name)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        log = logging.StreamHandler()
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)40s - %(lineno)4d - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        log.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(log)
        return logger

debug_obj = debugger(__name__)
logger = debug_obj.log()
```

Just added these `logger.info` statements in the place of `print()`
`logger.info('SOMETHING')`
`logger.info('NOTHING')`

I still don't see any logs in my driver from UDF. I got to know that UDF runs on a different process and on a JVM. Could anyone let me know how can I send `log.INFO/ERROR` from my UDF method to my driver logs as usual.

Answer (score 1):

The logs end up in the local JVM's of the executor that is actually processing the task.

Check the spark UI, select the executors and check the stdout & stderr for info and error logs.